# Larger indexes in MongoDB 5 compared to MongoDB 4

Tags: mongodb

I noticed that MongoDB database indexes take more space in MongoDB 5 than in MongoDB 4. I verified the phenomenon by testing as follows:

1. export (mongoexport) sample data of 100.000 documents out of some test environment (documents have MongoDB ObjectIds included)
2. import (mongoimport) these data to a fresh MongoDB 4.2.22 and a fresh Mongo 5.0.11 database
3. compare the collection statistics

Test-Result:

- same avgObjSize of 495 bytes in MongDB 4 and 5
- different avgIndex Size of _id-Index

  - MongoDB 4 → 10 bytes
  - MongoDB 5 → 19 bytes

Does anyone know what causes this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you’re seeing was caused by the new-ish (from MongoDB 5.0) WiredTiger feature of [Snapshot History Retention](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/wiredtiger/#snapshot-history-retention). The introduction of this feature changes a lot of WiredTiger internals, and this is one of the side effect of the change.

This issue was known, and was discussed in [SERVER-47652](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-47652), [WT-6082](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-6082), and [WT-6251](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-6251).